# foreach loop does not update to next item properly, but runs proper number of times

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have passed a list of Models from my controller to my View, and I am trying to use a foreach loop to display elements of each item in the list. The same item is being displayed each time, though my foreach loop runs the correct number of times (i.e. if my list has 3 items, it will create a table with 3 rows, but every row will be the same).

I have confirmed that my list is populated correctly by changing the order in which the elements are passed to the View. The table always displays elements of the first item in every row, once for every time the for loop runs. Here is my code in the view to iterate through my list:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.Name)</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => item.IPAddress)</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

This is my code from the controller to populate the list. I have verified that by changing the order of the elements, a different element will be displayed multiple times in the View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    List<IPWhitelist> model = new List<IPWhitelist>(); 
    long companyID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["CompanyID"].ToString());
    long branchID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["BranchID"].ToString());
    model = db.IPWhitelists.Where(w => w.CompanyID == companyID && w.BranchID == branchID && w.IsActive).OrderBy(w => w.Name).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

I am very stumped so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use MVC in a while, I think you have a problem in the syntax

If you want to iterate you can either use simply @item.Name and @item.IPAdress, and if you want to use the Html.DisplayFor, you have to use it as so:

```
<tbody>
@for (var i=0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => Modelitem[i].Name)</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(Modelitem => Modelitem[i].IPAddress)</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

DisplayFor helper can be used in this way:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>
           <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</b>
       </td>
   </tr>       
}
```